# Is it possible to run an exe file on a host computer via a website?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to run an .exe file from the host computer? For example, someone enters my website and it starts to run "mspaint.exe" on the website itself (people will see MS Paint and be able to use it). So, nothing is opened or running on the client side - only server side.

I tried searching for this, but I only get answers regarding opening a local exe file with a website.

thanks,
g3mini :D

Comment: Yes, but web servers do not run interactively, so you can't have any UI.

Comment: oh, any way of getting it to run interactively?
with javascript or php or anything

Comment: @SLaks That entirely depends on how you have things configured.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to access the remote desktop application via the web browser you will need a HTML5 VNC client. A popular one is Gaucamole @ http://guac-dev.org/. It can be configured to view only a single application instead of the remote desktop.

If you want the website to work as a trigger for remote applications and want the remote applications to work like they are being run on the client machine. This can be done over Microsoft's Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). I have seen this work flawlessly, but it requires a ton of work.

Comment: thanks for the link to guacamole :) might try it out and if it works it's worth the work ^^

Answer (score 4):

If I were to do this, I would have a set of VMs that run the software your clients would see.  Then, you can use one of the many web-based VNC clients available which could connect either directly to the VM, or via proxy.

The benefit of this approach is that after every user session, you can roll back the state of the VM to the way you configured it.  It also completely separates your code and what not from where the user is working with the remote software.

Comment: thanks :D, any idea on how to do this?

Comment: @user3147669 Yes... I just told you how to do it.  Do you have specific questions?  Do you need to know how to set up VMs?  How do integrate a VNC client?

Comment: i know you told me how to do it but what i'm wondering is indeed how to integrate a vnc client and make it connect to the vm automatically

Comment: @user3147669 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3240633/362536

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat, And I say that very losely... You will basically need to run the application inside a shell. Something like Xenocode is what you can use to accomplish this.

Comment: i might try to use xenocode see what happens, thanks :) it does make me install a lot of plugins and such though before it runs anything